# What are the best practices for hardening a hhvm ini file?

Tags: php

In order to improve security,

- Are there any best practices or "must have" to configure the HHVM settings?
- Are there any absolutely vital in terms of security?
- What is recommended for most use cases?

Researching in the official documentation, there are tons of settings to configure: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/INI-Settings

Answer (score 1):

I would surmise that security best practices for HHVM are similar to, or identical to those for PHP. In my experience, HHVM behaves mostly like PHP, except that it tends to enforce stricter constraints on variable types.

To be thorough:

1. **Harden the environment. The server software** of course:
   http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html
2. Where applicable, **distribute services across servers.** Databases on a server, Memcache on another, etc. To keep the system as failsafe as possible: isolate points of failure.
3. **Grant the minimum amount of required privileges** to any item on your web server. At the very least, the owner of files belonging to a web server should never be root, and writable folders should be kept outside of the web root. This, to limit the impact of privilege escalation, and to mitigate the risk of code upload and injection.
4. This is arguable, they are enabled by default, but many web hosts use **php.ini** to **disable functions like exec or proc_open.** In a shared environment, they give a shell to any php developer basically. On a vps, they might well grant a shell to the outside users. Privilege escalation is not far.
5. The rest, and **php.ini-specific items,** are discussed in sufficient detail in this article: http://www.madirish.net/199

Other considerations include **general fault-tolerance** and **memory consumption,** use lean software (prefer Nginx and its low memory footprint for example), so as to moderate the risk of denial-of-service, and possible debug, or compile-time files. Eq. you don't want just anyone to read core dumps whenever a component would fail (including HHVM), and HHVM produces **.hhvm.hhbc files** - cached bytecode files. That you also want to conceal, preserve, and perhaps manipulate in some minor ways.

More details (from 2012) are available here: http://hhvm.com/blog/4061/go-faster

Some still might apply.